# Receiving fake path while uploading

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

Whenever the uploading process happens through the Browsers rather than IE, the path 
 belongs to the file from client side systems is showing like "c:/fakepath/x.jpg"..! I tried out lot of
 Solutions from the web to rectify that, but nothing works..! If anybody successfully tackled this 
 problem before Just send me your solution..!
 HTML code that i used

```
<form name="xx"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="up"/>
</form>
```

My Java script..

```
alert(document.xx.up.value);
```

But it is displaying "c:/fakepath/x.jpg" in all browsers except IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a browser security restriction. You can't set the value of the file upload control via script, nor can you read the correct path.

Comment: Yeah its right.! I came to know about this while i'm surfing to find a remedy. Then how can we upload a file to our server..? is there any peculiar way to achieve that..? give me a clue.

Comment: The fact that it shows c:\fakepath\{file} doesn't mean that the file won't upload - it will. You just can't see the path.

Answer (score 1):

Modern browsers won't tell you what the actual path of the file is, because it's really none of your business as an application programmer, and is likely to contain private user information (e.g, their username).

There is no workaround. Learn to live without that information.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://davidwalsh.name/fakepath) shows a way to remove the 'fakepath' display:

> // Change the node's value by removing the fake path
>
> inputNode.value = fileInput.value.replace("C:\fakepath\", "");

Answer (score 0):

Change the ClientId of the AsyncFileUpload control from Inherit to AutoId

Answer (score 0):

Adding some few more steps to your code and introducing a change event, you could retrieve the file object from the event target if there is a file selected at all.

```
<form name="xx"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" onchange="fileChangeAction(event)" name="up"/>
</form>

<script>
    const fileChangeAction = ($event) => {
        let file;
        if($event.target) {
            if($event.target.files) {
                file = $event.target.files[0];
            }
        }
        console.log(file);
    }
</script>
```