# how to get client file full path with jquery or java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Receiving fake path while uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476473/receiving-fake-path-while-uploading)
>   [ASP.NET: Get file path on client’s machine (Any possible solutions/work arounds?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153627/asp-net-get-file-path-on-clients-machine-any-possible-solutions-work-arounds)

i need to get client file Full Path and send it to webservice. but i could not get path!because New browser for security issues not allow to access it for example in file upload.

Comment: Java Applet or Adobe Flash

Comment: You can't get the local file path. Browsers specifically hide this information so that javascript can't access it. It's a security issue

Comment: I heard there a way to deal with file system using Chrome started in a special mode : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429513/writing-to-local-file-system-in-chrome-extension

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly get the physical file path of client machine, because of browser security issue, as you mention in your question.

but you can do it using any third party technologies, like you can develop your file upload control in silver light or adobe flex/flash so it might be possible using this technologies to get directly client file path.